# how to extract strings from text file using regexp or powershell?

Tags: script, regex

Having a text file with

```
<td><tr>id"2222"</td></tr><td><tr>id"3333"</td></tr>
```

etc

I would want to extract every string that is between "" and write it on different lines

2222

3333

4444

Comment: Have you tried something? What doesn't work?

Comment: Do you REALLY have `<td><tr>` in your string and not `<tr><td>`?

Answer (score 0):

Its not powershell but notepad ++ find and replace regex you can remove all of that in about 5 minutes.

Reformat it with a carriage return as .csv

In Powershell

```
$string = <td><tr>id"2222"</td></tr><td><tr>id"3333"</td></tr>

$string -replace '<td><tr>id"','' -replace'</td></tr>','' -replace """", "`r`n" >>C:\testtext.txt
```

From a File

```
(Get-Content c:\test.txt) -replace '<td><tr>id"','' -replace'</td></tr>','' -replace """", "`r`n"   | Set-Content c:\test.txt
```

Sorry Can't Comment Yet

Not elegant but it works.